# Can we have this question re-instated?

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

Once a question is deleted by community, I can no longer flag it for moderator review.

Can we have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346796/getting-row-from-gridview-in-dev-express) re-instated? The Edit made it a viable question, but my guess is that it was thrown over the 'offensive' limit from people not 'refreshing' for the edit.

**Feature Request**: Maybe if someone clicks 'flag', there ought to be a dialog (much like a new answer pops up at the top of the screen) telling them that the question has been edited since they last viewed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, 'tis back. It was passionate enough to trip my work filtering! (I can side-step...).

I guess there's a [s**t-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) badge in the offing for anyone with an answer...

Answer (score 3):

Wow. That guy hates DevExpress. A lot.

Maybe he'll just post the question again. But respectfully. Maybe.

Because Diago is curious, here's the posting. Stop reading now if you get offended by language:

> how the f*** should someone get a
>   f***ing row on a f***ing gridcontrol
>   of devexpress it should be simple,
>   just a gridview.Row or gridview.GetRow
>   but helloooo, devexpress makes things
>   difficult, why the f*** should they
>   not let this as the simple way it was.
>   it drives you crazy searching a
>   f***ing way to get a damn row from a
>   gridview. Why?!
>
> p.s: to the devexpress owner: f*** you

Comment: Dammit now I am curious. I hate not having enough rep on SO :(

Comment: @Eric - Thanks and ouch. I am also not crazy bout them but that is scary!

Comment: Not a problem. Marc has made that public, now, but my word that's a great rant.

Comment: Even his name has the reference. Pianful [fc_devexpress?]

Comment: If you have this version, do you have the edited version of the question?

Answer (score 2):

This question can be ignored utterly and ought to have no bearing on the design of the moderation system.

But, it is still a very rare (and fascinating) case.

While the edited version was no longer offensive, it became so simplistic that it was remained a bad question (and possible dupe).

The OP ought to have included what he had tried, what barriers were experienced and so forth.

<sub>But top marks to Gortok for an excellent edit</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Wow. What a moral dilemma. While I agree this question is much better written, I don't know if it really deserved to be re-opened after the way the OP phrased it. I mean, I know that some words may slip sometimes from some lips, but that was just incredible.

Comment: It would help if the moderators could delete the original revision.

Comment: Maybe it should be wiki-fied so the OP doesn't gain any rep?

Comment: @Rob: If you wikify the question, the answers don't gain rep either, unfortunately.

Comment: Everybody loses.

Comment: Wiki isn't supposed to be used to take away (or bow out from) the rep process. Wiki questions are supposed to support a specific type of question in the system. I keep seeing users set their answers to wiki because they probably feel their answer would be voted down. Kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd delete that very first version of the question.  There is nothing constructive in that and it still tarnishes the question.  Jonathan is spot on...